# Why does a custom hook that uses another hooks value via useContext only shows its initial value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-state-management

I'm trying to reuse a bunch of custom hooks without re-invoking them and without maintaining an order through which I'll have to pass cascading parameters from one hook to the other.

A working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-firefly-mlhdw?file=/src/App.js:0-1158

Given the following code:

```js
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const globalContext = React.createContext({
  user: null,
  pet: null
});

const usePet = () => {
  const [pet, setPet] = useState(null);
 
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setPet("Dog");
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return pet;
};

const useUser = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  // I want to proxy pet via the context so that I won't have to re-invoke its side-effects again
  const { pet } = useContext(globalContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setUser("john");
    }, 500);
  }, []);

  // This is only called once with the default value (null)
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Called from user!", { pet });
  }, [pet]);

  return user;
};

export const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const user = useUser();
  const pet = usePet();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("StateProvider", { user, pet });
  }, [user, pet]);

  return (
    <globalContext.Provider value={{ user, pet }}>
      {children}
    </globalContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const { user, pet } = useContext(globalContext);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>
        {pet} {user}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}

// imagine an index.js that's wrapping the App component like this:
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <StateProvider>
      <App />
    </StateProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

What I'm expecting to see in the console output is the following

```
Called from user! {pet: null}
StateProvider {user: null, pet: null}
StateProvider {user: "john", pet: null}
StateProvider {user: "john", pet: "Dog"}
Called from user! {pet: "Dog"}
```

But I'm not getting any updates inside `useUser` other than the initial state:

```
Called from user! {pet: null}
StateProvider {user: null, pet: null}
StateProvider {user: "john", pet: null}
StateProvider {user: "john", pet: "Dog"}
<!-- no update here, pet is still null for the useUser hook -->
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to achieve that? if it is, what am I missing here?
2. If it's not possible, is there a more elegant way of passing data between custom hooks without re-invoking them (creating a new state context for each invocation) and without passing parameters from one another, which will force me to also maintain order between everything?

Just to clarify - the UI is working as expected and all the values are rendered correctly inside the component.

Also, when passing the parameters directly to the hook, things are also in order

```js
const pet = usePet(); 
const user = useUser(pet); //this will work as it doesn't go through the context
```

Comment: You are running `useUser` outside the context tree, it will never work unless you you run it below the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand why your expectations are being violated, you must first understand how the [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) works, including the [`useContext`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) hook.

I'll include an especially relevant snippet here:

> ### useContext
>
> ```js
> const value = useContext(MyContext);
> ```
>
> Accepts a context object (the value returned from `React.createContext`) and returns the current context value for that context. The current context value is determined by the `value` prop of the nearest `<MyContext.Provider>` above the calling component in the tree.

When you use the context hook, your component which invokes the hook only receives updates when the context is updated. **If you invoke the hook outside the root of a context provider tree, there will never be an update.** This is what's happening in your example code.

An easy solution to this is to simply move the invocation of the hooks which depend on the context into a separate component below the context provider root. However, because of the way that your custom hooks are co-dependent (and neither actually update the context itself), this still leaves you in a stalemate of circular dependency.

To address this, you must give yourself the ability to update the context: by including a state setter that you can invoke with values to update the state.

In the following refactor of your code, I've made both of these changes:

> This is a very common pattern, and the most common iteration of it is using the `useReducer` hook in combination with the context API. You can find lots of examples by querying for `react state context`.

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.17.2/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useState,
} = React;

const initialContextState = {pet: null, user: null};

// You don't need to supply a default value here because you're no longer
// using it outside the provider root:
// const defaultContextValue = [initialContextState, () => {}];
// const appContext = createContext(defaultContextValue);

const appContext = createContext();

const usePet = () => {
  const [{pet}, setState] = useContext(appContext);
  useEffect(() => setTimeout(() => setState(state => ({...state, pet: 'Dog'})), 3000), [setState]);
  return pet;
};

const useUser = () => {
  const [{pet, user}, setState] = useContext(appContext);
  useEffect(() => setTimeout(() => setState(state => ({...state, user: 'John'})), 500), [setState]);
  useEffect(() => console.log('Called from user!', {pet}), [pet]);
  return user;
};

// This must be rendered within the context provider root
const ContextDependentHooksInvoker = () => {
  const pet = usePet();
  const user = useUser();

  useEffect(
    () => console.log('ContextDependentHooksInvoker', {pet, user}),
    [user, pet],
  );

  return null;
};

const StateProvider = ({children}) => {
  const stateWithSetter = useState(initialContextState);
  return (
    <appContext.Provider value={stateWithSetter}>
      <ContextDependentHooksInvoker />
      {children}
    </appContext.Provider>
  );
};

function App () {
  const [{pet, user}] = useContext(appContext);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>{pet} {user}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

function Example () {
  return (
    <React.StrictMode>
      <StateProvider>
        <App />
      </StateProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

**1. Yes, this is possible to achieve.**

The thing that was missing here is that your `useUser()` is called inside `StateProvider` component, i.e. on the same level with the context provider, whereas for `useContext()` to work, it has to be called **one level down** the context provider (`StateProvider` as a wrapper). In this case, it would be your `App` component.

A working code would be as follow:

```
export default function App() {
  const { user, pet } = useContext(globalContext);

  // this one will print out in console
  // Called from user!  {pet: "Dog"}
  // as expected
  const userWithInContext = useUser();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>
        {pet} {user}
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tested it and it worked. I did not make any other changes, merely setting a new `userWithInContext` variable up there, using the same `useUser()` logic you provided. In console it will print these outputs:

```
// this is from userWithInContext inside App component
Called from user! {pet: "Dog"}
// this is from user variable inside StateProvider component
Called from user! {pet: null}
```

**2. Since it is possible** to achieve what you want, this is just a side note about elegance and readability as of [why you may not want to call useContext() inside a custom hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147479/is-it-better-to-pass-context-to-a-custom-hook-or-call-usecontext-inside-the-cust).

Comment: Thanks for your thorough comment @kvooak , however your solution requires me to re-invoke `useUser()` again - the exact thing I'm trying to avoid doing.

I also want to clarify that the UI indeed renders as expected, regardless of the value inside `useUser()`

I wonder why passing a parameter to the hook will actually pull the update through:

`const pet = usePet(); const user = useUser(pet); //this will work as it doesn't go through the context`