# useContext values return undefined in testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to testing and using Enzyme and Jest to write very simple tests. I just want to check whether the component renders or not. However, (I guess) because my component uses `useContext` hook, test case automatically returns undefined for all values come from the Context.

In component:

```
const { count, setCount } = useContext(Context);
```

Test case:

```
it('should render', () => {
  const component = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  const wrapper = component.find('myClassName');
  expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Test Result: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Is there a simple way that always works with `useContext` and other hooks to test simple things?

Comment: u got this fixed? im having same issue

Comment: Did you provide a default value for your context when you created it via `createContext`?

Comment: @bensampaio I did, still undefined

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that when you shallow rendering a component, `Context` will be ignored. So try mounting your component instead of shallow rendering it like so:

```
import { mount } from "enzyme"; // mount instead of `shallow` here

...
it('should render', () => {
  const component = mount(<MyComponent />); // `mount` here as well
  const wrapper = component.find('myClassName');
  expect(wrapper.length).toBe(1);
});
```

Comment: the mount didn't helped in my case I still get this undefinded error

Comment: Mount is not helping me either. I also still get cant read property of undefined error.