# How to test Styled Component that includes children components and consumes a context?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have a parent component called `DismissButton`:

```js
    import React, { useContext } from 'react';
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    import { StyledDismissButton } from './Styled';
    import { IoClose } from 'react-icons/io5';
    import VisibilityContext from '../../context';
    
    export const DismissButton = () => {
       const { setVisible } = useContext(VisibilityContext);
       const hideToast = () => setVisible(false);
       return (
          <StyledDismissButton aria-label="Close" onClick={hideToast}>
             <IoClose />
          </StyledDismissButton>
       );
    };
    
    StyledDismissButton.propTypes = {
       onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    };
    
    export { StyledDismissButton };
```

It consumes this `context`:

```js
    import { createContext } from 'react';
    
    const initialState = {
       visible: true,
       setVisible: () => {},
    };
    const VisibilityContext = createContext(initialState);
    
    export default VisibilityContext;
```

It holds a child component `StyledDissmissButton`:

```js
import styled from "styled-components";
const StyledDismissButton = styled.span`
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

export { StyledDismissButton };
```

I want to test `DismissButton` with Enzyme and Jest but I failed each time because the component consumes a context. I've tried [this soltion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691799/how-to-test-a-react-component-that-is-dependent-on-usecontext-hook) but it does not work for me.

### Test

```js
import 'jsdom-global/register';
import React from 'react';
import Enzyme, { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';
import DismissButton, { StyledDismissButton } from './index';
import { IoClose } from 'react-icons/io';
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

it('renders one <StyledDissmisButton> when passed in', () => {
   const contextValue = {
      visible: true,
      setVisible: () => {},
      hideToast() {
         this.setVisible(false);
      },
   };

   const element = shallow(<DismissButton />);
   expect(
      element.contains(
         <StyledDismissButton aria-label="Close" onClick={contextValue.hideToast}>
            <IoClose />
         </StyledDismissButton>
      )
   ).toEqual(true);
});
```

#### Test Result

```
 expect(received).toEqual(expected)
    
    Expected value to equal:
      true
    Received:
      false
      
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/Toast/Header/DismissButton/index.test.js:32:7)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 failed, 4 passed, 5 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        13.773s
```

You can check the repos on [React Toast](https://codesandbox.io/s/5kfz9)

### Debugging result

```js
    <TestComponent>
            <Component>
              <styled.span aria-label="Close" onClick={[Function: hideToast]}>
                <span aria-label="Close" onClick={[Function: hideToast]} className="sc-bdnxRM gsGVlo">
                  <IoClose>
                    <IconBase attr={{...}}>
                      <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" strokeWidth="0" viewBox="0 0 512 512" className={[undefined]} style={{...}} height="1em" width="1em" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M289.94 256l95-95A24 24 0 00351 127l-95 95-95-95a24 24 0 00-34 34l95 95-95 95a24 24 0 1034 34l95-95 95 95a24 24 0 0034-34z" />
                      </svg>
                    </IconBase>
                  </IoClose>
                </span>
              </styled.span>
            </Component>
   </TestComponent>
```

### Update

After a deep focusing I've found that Styled Component generates add a class to the component which makes the matching impossible:

```
<span aria-label="Close" onClick={[Function: hideToast]} className="sc-bdnxRM gsGVlo">
```

But I don't know how to pass that class in the test?

Comment: Could you please provide more context as to what actually gets rendered in your test case? Perhaps the output of something like `wrapper.debug()` would tell me more, my guess would be that the onClick method you are checking in `wrapper.contains()` doesn't match the one in the component since that one is inlined, while the one you are comparing to is statically defined in the context.

Comment: @FilipKaštovský, you can check  [the repo](https://codesandbox.io/s/5kfz9).

Answer (score 0):

The reason the test fails is because functions `hideToast` created in the scope of the component and `hideToast` defined in the test are referentially different. When `wrapper.contains` checks the `onClick` props on `StyledDismissButton`, it fails, since the two functions are not the same.

One way to go around this is to implement `hideToast` in the context itself and use it as provided by the `useContext` hook.

```
const initialState = {
   visible: true,
   setVisible: () => {},
   hideToast(){
      this.setVisible(false)
   }
};
```

```
export const DismissButton = () => {
   const { hideToast } = useContext(VisibilityContext);

   return (
      <StyledDismissButton aria-label="Close" onClick={hideToast}>
         <IoClose />
      </StyledDismissButton>
   );
};
```

Props now match, the test passes.

```
describe('<DismissButton/>', () => {
   it('renders one <StyledDissmisButton> when passed in', () => {
      const contextValue = {
         visible: true,
         setVisible: () => {},
         hideToast(){
            this.setVisible(false)
         }
      };
 
      const TestComponent = () => {
         return (
            <Context.Provider value={contextValue}>
               <DismissButton />
            </Context.Provider>
         );
      };
      const element = mount(<TestComponent />);
   
      expect(
         element.contains(
            <StyledDismissButton aria-label="Close" onClick={contextValue.hideToast}>
               <IoClose />
            </StyledDismissButton>
         )
      ).toEqual(true);
   });
});
```

[Codesandbox fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-toast-forked-xo1q0?file=/src/components/Toast/Header/DismissButton/index.test.js)

Comment: Stir getting the same error, could you run the test on the giving repo on sandbox.

Comment: I was having issues with devdependencies on the sandbox, so I cloned the project locally and debugged it there, but I will try to make it work in the sandbox as well

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the working codesandbox fork

Comment: In the original repo there was a typo in this import in `index.test.js`: `import { IoClose } from "react-icons/io";`, should be `import { IoClose } from "react-icons/io5";` that made the test run correctly. My IDE lit that up but i forgot to reflect that change in the sandbox until now

Comment: Also I would like to point out that there are some situations where the answer might not be applicable. in my experience, it is better to assert on different things then if a react subtree is contained in the wrapper, and the question problem is one of the reasons why. I used html snapshot testing with enzyme instead for a while, since I found it way more straight forward and was really only concerned about the final result of the render (after simulating a few events to get to the desired state). Unit tests mostly covered any internal logic and I found no benefit in testing react itself.