# How to test a component in react using testing library depends on AppContext

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

[image] I need to test a component(ServiceRequestDetails).That component has a layout that uses AppCOntext data.
While testing ServiceRequestDetails I got the error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'darkMode')..

`ServiceRequestDetails.js` Page. From here I tested text "Service Request Details".But I got an error.Because in the layout component I used Appcontext.

```
export function ServiceRequestDetails(props) {
    const ctx = useContext(AppContext);
  
    return (
        <>
            <Layout
                page="servicerequestdetails"
                title={navigationLinks()}
                subTitle={pageSubTitle()}
                showHelp={true}
                helpText={"Help"}
                helpIcon={<QuestionCircleOutlined />}
                onHelpClick={() => setShowHelpModal(!showHelpModal)}
                helpToggle={showHelpModal}
                helpTemplate={<ViewServiceRequest />}
            >

                <div className="flex items-center">
                    <div className="pr-2">
                      <img src="/images/icons/services.svg" alt="filter" />
                    </div>
                    <h3 className="text-lg font-medium">Service Request Details</h3>
                </div>

          </Layout>
        </>
    )
}
```

`ServiceRequestDetails.test.js`.It is my test case for service request details page.
From here how to resolve AppCOntext issue.

```
test('Testing For title', () => {
  render(
    <Router>
      <ServiceRequestDetails/>
    </Router>
  )
  expect(screen.getByText("Service Request Details")).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54691799/how-to-test-a-react-component-that-is-dependent-on-usecontext-hook)

Comment: Your code didn't use `ctx`. Please provide [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)